# Validating accordion div elements appended using jquery laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, validation, accordion

I have an accordion div containing text input fields and file uploads. On clicking a button the same div gets appended. I want to validate the fields inside the accordion div.

Here is my view

```
<div id="accordion">
   <div class="group" id="groupId">
      <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="ENTER QUESTION 1" name="question_name[]" id="question_name0">
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="file-upload col-md-4">
            <label for="question_image_paths0">Upload image/Video <span class="upload">upload</span></label>
            <input type="file" name="question_image_path[]" id="question_image_paths0" accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .gif, .png, .mp3, .mp4, .wma" />
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="here"></div>
</div>
```

On clicking a button another div gets appended.

```
$("#here").append(
  '<div class="group" id="groupId' + i + '">' +
    '<div class="form-group row">' +
      '<div class="col-md-12">' +
        '<input class="form-control" name="question_name[]" id="question_name' + j + '" placeholder="ENTER QUESTION ' + i + '">' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '<div class="form-group row">' +
      '<div class="file-upload col-md-4">' +
        '<label for="question_image_paths' + j + '">Upload image/Video <span class="upload">upload</span></label>' +
        '<input type="file"  name="question_image_path[]" id="question_image_paths' + j + '" accept=".jpeg, .jpg, .gif, .png, .mp3, .mp4, .wma"/>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>');
```

I want to validate each field inside the accordion div. My ajax result on validation failure calls  a function showValidation() to catch the errors.

```
function showValidation(response) {
    var errTextboxClass = 'error';
    var errMsg = '';
    var j = 0;
    var respArray = JSON.parse(response.responseText).errors;
    $('.' + errTextboxClass).remove();
    $.each(respArray, function (k, v) {
        alert(k);
        j = parseInt(j) + 1; //alert("The question_name."+i+" field is required.");
        var $this = $('#' + k);
        $('#' + k).after('<span class="' + errTextboxClass + '" style="color:#e03b3b">' + v + '</span>');
        if (j == 1)
            $('#' + k).focus();

    });
}
```

In my Rule Request I defined, the rule as below

```
$rules =  [
    "question_name.*" => 'required',
    "question_image_path.*" => 'required'
];
```

But this one does not catch any error. But firebug shows validation errors as well.

I get response like this

> {"message":"The given data was invalid.","errors":{"question_image_path.0":["The question image path.0 field is required."],"question_name.0":["Enter Question."]}}

GroupRequest.php

```
public function rules(Req $request)
{
    $rules =  [
      "question_name.*" => 'required',
      "question_image_path.*" => 'required'
    ];
}
```

Comment: where is the laravel code part of your question?

Comment: My function uses GroupRequest to perform vlaidation.  public function storeGroup(GroupRequest $request){}

Comment: why not place the input field within the <form></form>